SharePoint modern view, JSON, Change the height of gallery cards dynamically
We would like to adjust the height of each card dynamically to the content of each card (see screenshot below). I already tried with "height": "auto", but the cards overlaps after this or half of the content is cut if you use group by.
To hide the columns in the gallery I used.
"style": {
              "display": "=if([$Description] == '', 'none', 'block')"
            }

The gallery view:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 600,
  "width": 254,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [


